# Upgrade to msysgit 1.7.0.2?

Tags: upgrade, msysgit

I know this question is probably stoopid. But I just don't want to cause any hickups with my work system (Win7).

How do I upgrade the software? Do I just replace the existing version or do I need to remove the one I'm having and then install the new version?
I tried to find some info on the net but did not find any info on upgrading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MsysGit uses a proper installer so you can just download and run the installer for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

The code base distinguishes between "Git for Windows" which is simply the runnable application. This will install with a proper installer, or there is a portable version as well. [downloads list](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)

There is then the MsysGit which has the full source code so that you can contribute to the project, or at least try your own local fixes and recompile a local release etc. [MSysGit:InstallMSysGit](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/MSysGit%3aInstallMSysGit)

Comment: The install instruction are now at https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/i/n/s/MSysGit~InstallMSysGit_1a31.html because kernel.org had a security issue that it's working through.